# How to write a script that can automatically update a graphic card in Win10?

Tags: python, automation, windows-10

I am trying to write a python to do these activities in Win 10.

Go to Device Manager -> Display Adapter -> right click and select to update Driver -> go to some path to install the new driver -> after installation is completed, restart the PC.

I am trying to study how to write automation test using Python or other kinds of script languages. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You've said you're trying, in that case you must have some code that you've tried, sharing it would make it easier to help you

Comment: To be honest, I completely have no idea what to start with